# Property 'context' does not exist on type 'DocumentsViewerWebPart'

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx, reactjs

I have the following code inside my .ts file in SPFx web part:-

```
export default class DocumentsViewerWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IDocumentsViewerWebPartProps> {
  private _themeProvider: ThemeProvider;
  private _themeVariant: IReadonlyTheme | undefined;

  protected async onInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.setTheme();

    await super.onInit();
  }

  /**
   * Update the current theme variant reference and re-render.
   *
   * @param args The new theme
   */
  private _handleThemeChangedEvent(args: ThemeChangedEventArgs): void {
    this._themeVariant = args.theme;
    this.render();
  }

  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IDocumentsViewerProps> = React.createElement(DocumentsViewer, {
      context: this.context,
      groupByColumn: this.properties.groupByColumn,
      themeVariant: this._themeVariant,
      connectToSiteUrl: this.properties.connectToSiteUrl,
      connectToListTitle: this.properties.connectToListTitle,
      listTitleForFolderIcons: this.properties.listTitleForFolderIcons,
    });
```

but i am getting these reference errors:-

Property 'context' does not exist on type 'DocumentsViewerWebPart'.

Property 'properties' does not exist on type 'DocumentsViewerWebPart'

Property 'domElement' does not exist on type 'DocumentsViewerWebPart'.

Any advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope, you have already solved this. For the people who need it that my solution is run -> npm i